# Scanner not asking input of string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

In the below code:

```
secondI = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("double");
secondD = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("string");
secondS = scan.nextLine();
```

After entering the double value, it is skipping the string entry part. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
secondI = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("double");
secondD = scan.nextDouble();

scan.nextLine();

System.out.println("string");
secondS = scan.nextLine();
```

*You need to have this extra nextline statement* which consumes the remaining section of that line which you entered for the double value.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
secondS = scan.next();
```

instead of

```
secondS = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation for `Scanner.nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.

Try using other methods of the `Scanner` class such as [`Scanner.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next())